# Setting up TFVC repo in Visual Studio Code for Mac

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-devops, tfvc

I am trying to to set up a Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC) repository hosted in VSTS on my Visual Studio Code for Mac. I haven't used Visual Studio at all. Apparently, my client is using TFVC system as their main approach for repo management.

However, I tried downloading the source as a Zip from the VSTS web site but Visual Studio Code for Mac (with the VSTS extension configured) did not identify that folder is a VSTS repo (Showing the "team" icon).

Tutorial I followed to configure - https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/blob/master/TFVC_README.md#quick-start

[image]

May I know what I am not doing right here? or simply is it because you can't work with VSTS with MacOS system.

I don't have a PC btw

Comment: Do you solve this issue with my solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can't download the source as zip.

You can create workspace and get the source through tf command (TEE cli): [Cross-Platform Command-Line Client- Beginner's Guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873092(v=vs.120).aspx).

Then click File > Open Folder > Select that folder to open, then click Team icon to login.

On the other hand, you can use TEE in eclipse to do that through UI way.