# Setup VSTS in VSCode

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, azure-devops

I recently downloaded VSCode for use on my Mac.  I installed the TFS plugin but none of the tutorials work in terms of getting connected. This is the [guide](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/blob/master/TFVC_README.md#quick-start) I am following

If I goto Source Control then click the "..." I dont get an option for VSTS I only get an option to Add Additional SCM providers.. If I click on this it shows me a list which contains the plugin I have already downloaded, which says its installed.

I even tried downloading a branch as a Zip from the VSTS portal and opening that in VSCode, but it did not prompt me to connect to VSTS.

I also tried to manually set the settings and have added these, but to no avail.

```
{
    "team.remoteUrl": "https://***.visualstudio.com",
    "tfvc.location": "/Users/***/Documents/TFS",
}
```

**Update**

I installed TFVS as per this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/chris-pilcher/a3f14eb081d7ab983e5c).
I have changed my user settings to

```
{
    "tfvc.location": "/usr/local/Cellar/tee-clc/14.123.1/libexec/tf",
}
```

Unfortunately I still cannot sign in when running `team signin` as I get the error

> No Team Services or Team Foundation Server repository configuration
>   was found. Ensure you've opened a folder that contains a repository.

**TF Output**

```
Last login: Sun Apr 22 11:43:20 on ttys000
/usr/local/Cellar/tee-clc/14.123.1/libexec/tf ; exit;
MacBook-Pro:~ ***$ /usr/local/Cellar/tee-clc/14.123.1/libexec/tf ; exit;
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
Deleting expired sessions...6 completed.

[Process completed]
```

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

First you need full path for `tf.exe` eg for visual studio 2017.

```
"tfvc.location": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Community\\Common7\\IDE\\CommonExtensions\\Microsoft\\TeamFoundation\\Team Explorer\\Tf.exe"
```

then you need to press `ctrl + shift + p` and search for `Team: signin`
you will be asked to select your login experience select `.... (new experience)`

then a code will appear just copy it and press `enter` your browser will open with a page asks you to enter your code after that you will sign in with your `vsts` account and that's it you'r in!

Comment: Thanks! When I do this I get `No Team Services or Team Foundation Server repository configuration was found. Ensure you've opened a folder that contains a repository.` - P.s. updated my question with more information

Comment: make sure that `tfvc.location` path exists (the path supplied is if you have visual studio 2017 installed) if not make sure to download `Team explorer every where` and point to the excutable file [from here](https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases) you will need `CLC` one

Comment: Are you able to run `tf` command successfully and what is the output

Comment: Hey, thanks for help, if I just run `tf` I get the output I put in my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to map files to local machine through TF command (**Create Workspace and Checkout** section in the article you provided) or TEE UI (eclipse), then you can open that folder and connect to VSTS.

Similar thread: [Setting up TFVC repo in Visual Studio Code for Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48819539/setting-up-tfvc-repo-in-visual-studio-code-for-mac)